# elasticsearch 5 : search with exclude

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I try to search on an index for person (by first name and last name) , this part is pretty simple :

```
GET /my_index/persons/search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query" : "john doe"
        }
    }
}
```

In addition I want to exclude the person having a specific id, I tried with a `filter` clause but i wasn't able to properly form the query, can you guys help me ?

---

EDIT

I've tried

```js
{
    "query":{
        "multi_match":{
            "query":"anne mirande",
            "fields":[
                "first_name",
                "last_name"
            ],
            "type":"cross_fields",
            "operator":"and"
        }
    },
    "filter":{
        "not":{
            "term":{
                "id":1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws be this : **Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filter].**

Comment: `filter` should be inside `query bool`. Refer this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```
GET /my_index/persons/search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term": {
          "name": {
            "value": "john doe"
          }
        }}
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {"term": {
          "_id": {
            "value": "1"
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked for me, I guess I had issues because I'm using elastic5

Comment: The newer, the better!